# Insert trigger with an IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to fire a trigger based on a condition and below is my sql. How do i include an `IF` statement in this trigger to fire if `ac_mail = '1@mail.com'`

```
CREATE TRIGGER username
ON temp                   
AFTER INSERT                    
AS                    
DECLARE @var1 int ,@var2 char (100)  

select @var1 = al_id, @var2 = ac_mail

From temp                   

BEGIN                    




INSERT INTO user (v_id,v_m)                    
VALUES (@var1,@var2)      




END
```

The trigger should only fire if `ac_mail = '1@mail.com'`

Comment: Where do `al_id` and `ac_mail` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER username
ON temp                   
AFTER INSERT                    
AS                    

DECLARE @var1 int ,@var2 char (100)  

Select   @var1 = al_id
        ,@var2 = ac_mail
From    inserted

IF @var2 = '1@mail.com'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user (v_id,v_m)                    
    VALUES (@var1,@var2)      
END
```

Comment: This doesn't support multiple operations. Scalar values in a trigger are almost always going to have this problem.

Comment: Sean Lange is right, scalar values in trigger will only insert first record while multiple operation. If there would be multiple operation then "Damien_The_Unbeliever" answer is perfect one.

Comment: @MihirShah - according to [`SELECT @local_variable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx): "If the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned". However, in the absence of an `ORDER BY`, it's not defined what order rows will be returned in. So we can't even say it's the "first" record (because, again, this is ill-defined)

Answer (score 7):

Triggers can fire for *multiple* rows - so using scalar variables to capture the data is usually wrong. As is querying the base table rather than [`inserted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) - `inserted` contains just the rows that caused the trigger to fire, whereas you're querying temp for any random row. And finally, of course, as I've said twice now, multiple rows. So you don't want an if because *some* of those rows might match your condition and other might *not* match.

I think you want:

```
CREATE TRIGGER username
ON temp                   
AFTER INSERT                    
AS                    
INSERT INTO user (v_id,v_m)                    
select al_id,ac_mail from inserted where ac_mail = '1@mail.com'
```

See how much simpler it is?

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER username
After INSERT ON temp
  REFERENCING NEW ROW AS New
FOR EACH ROW
  if(New.ac_mail=='1@mail.com')
  begin
  INSERT INTO user (v_id,v_m)                    
    VALUES (New.al_id,New.ac_mail)     
  end
```

Comment: [tag:sql-server] triggers don't support `REFERENCING` nor `FOR EACH ROW`. They fire once per statement.

Comment: I am specify to sql only

Comment: My point being, the question is tagged [tag:sql-server]. So a solution that doesn't work for SQL Server probably isn't correct.