# Trigger after insert SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

The trigger successfully gets executed in the MSSM and in the front end application when the insert query is executed the application just hangs and stops responding. But when I put a hardcoded value instead of the last inserted value, it is working perfectly fine. I am not sure if my last inserted syntax is wrong or I am going wrong somewhere else.

What I am trying to do here is from one Database table, I am trying to get the last inserted unique id and insert that into another database's table with current timestamp.

Help is really appreciated in this.

```
USE [Dummy_Ibus]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[insert_veh_bus] ON [dbo].[tcbus]
AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @last_inserted_unique_id NUMERIC(10,0);

SET @last_inserted_unique_id = 0;

select @last_inserted_unique_id = inserted.unique_id from inserted;

INSERT INTO bbus_sync.dbo.sync_history(unique_id,created_on) VALUES(@last_inserted_unique_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

END
```

Comment: Make sure there would not be a permission issue with bbus_sync database ? second, don't use scalar variable in trigger, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30891964/insert-trigger-with-an-if-statement/30892169#30892169.

Comment: 1. Permissions are there, user has DBO level permission.
2. I even tried this 
INSERT INTO bbus_sync.dbo.sync_history(unique_id,created_on) VALUES((select inserted.unique_id from inserted;) , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )

Comment: why use values, use directly INSERT INTO bbus_sync.dbo.sync_history(unique_id,created_on) select unique_id,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from inserted